# Opening and showing fits images in python

Tags: python, image, show, dimension, fits

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
def openfit(b):
    hdu_list = fits.open(b)
    hdu_list.info()
    image_data = hdu_list[0].data
    plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

 openfit(r"C:\Users\kapla_000\Desktop\barkin\bilgisayar\goruntu\HorseHead.fits")
```

i use this piece of code to open and show my HorseHead fits image which i took from (http://www.astropy.org/astropy-tutorials/FITS-images.html)

```
openfit(r"C:\Users\kapla_000\Desktop\barkin\bilgisayar\goruntu\NGC2392_CXO.fits")
```

when i try to use the same code to open NGC2392_CXO(http://people.sabanciuniv.edu/ersing/proj102/    )

i get the error on line : "plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')"

```
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
  File "C:\Users\kapla_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3022, in imshow
**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kapla_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kapla_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4947, in imshow
im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\kapla_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 449, in set_data
raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

i think the problem is about dimensions of the image files.
The line "hdu_list.info()" gives the properties of the image fits file.and for HorseHead it gives

```
Filename:                
C:\Users\kapla_000\Desktop\barkin\bilgisayar\goruntu\HorseHead.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU     161   (891, 893)   int16   
1    er.mask     TableHDU        25   1600R x 4C   [F6.2, F6.2, F6.2, F6.2]
```

And for NGC2392_CXO the same line gives

```
Filename:   
C:\Users\kapla_000\Desktop\barkin\bilgisayar\goruntu\NGC2392_CXO.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU      32   ()              
1    EVENTS      BinTableHDU    884   238647R x 19C   [1D, 1I, 1I, 1J, 1I,     
1I, 1I, 1I, 1E, 1E, 1E, 1E, 1J, 1J, 1E, 1J, 1I, 1I, 32X]   
2    GTI         BinTableHDU     28   1R x 2C      [1D, 1D]
```

In the 0th index of HorseHead list it has integer dimensions where NGC2392_CXO has no dimension. I can't seem to sort out how to view the NGC2392_CXO

Comment: According to ImageMagick, the NGC2392_CXO image size is 64x238647 pixels. I think that it is the sheer size that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the brief comment, but you'll probably save yourself a lot of trouble if you use aplpy.

Answer (score 3):

The file you're trying to open doesn't contain an image, technically, as far as the FITS format is concerned. The Primary HDU has no data and the other two HDUs are tables, not images.  It's possible for some conventions to store images in tables but the column structure doesn't look like it in this case, though looking at the column names would provide some insight.

But in general if you want to display FITS images with Python you'll often have the most immediate and effortless results if you at least start with [aplpy](https://aplpy.github.io). But for this particular file I'm not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: I think [astropy](https://www.astropy.org/) is what people are using now.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney APLpy is an [astropy affiliated package](https://www.astropy.org/affiliated/index.html#affiliated-package-list).  Astropy itself contains libraries and utilities related to image processing but nothing specific for effortless image display.